# Independent persons founding personal fiefdoms

Tags: exploration, age-of-discovery, kingdom

**Question:**

I am interested to know of any more possible instances like Sarawak and the Cocos-Keeling Islands described below, where individuals have managed to establish de facto fiefdoms or states lasting a significant amount of time. I am guessing there may of been more occurrences like these in the Age of Discovery, but i have not managed to find any.

**White Rajahs of Sarawak**

James Brooke received territory from the Sultan of Brunei as a reward for helping the Sultan fight of insurgents. The Brookes ruled Sarawak for three generations until it was ceded in the aftermath of WW2.

**Kingdom of the Cocos Islands**

John Clunies-Ross established a de facto kingdom in the Cocos Islands in the beginning of the 1800s when he established a settlement on the islands. The Clunies-Ross ruled the islands until 1978 when the islands where sold to Australia.

Comment: Does Edessa count?

Comment: Sort of, but not really. Baldwin inherited the fiefdom from his adopted father.

Comment: Kiliaen van Rensselaer, William Penn, the Calverts, Eric the Red, Ivarr the Boneless, Cecil Rhodes?

Comment: I think that instead of "independent" "individuals" this question is maybe about cases when rulers were introduced despite being of entirely alien ethnicity and culture and social class.

Comment: @kubanczyk In most cases that fits the description, but as for example in the case of the Cocos Islands, Clunie-Ross settled the island and introduced the population himself